# Radio button default value

Tags: kentico

[image]

As the pictures shown, I want to make the "Grid view" as the default checked.
Where should I configure the default value? How?

[image: As displayed in the WebPart initialization]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up above where you define your field name is a default value textbox.  Set the value in the textbox to one of the text options in your "list of options".  Since you do not have semi-colon separated lines, your text is your value.  In your case you can set the Default value = "Gird view" (you spelled it wrong in your list of options box).

If you have a listing with a semi-colon separated line of value and text it might look like this:

grid;Grid view
list;List view
row;Row view

Then you might use "grid" as your default value.